# Is there a way to one-button screenshot a single window's contents (not the frame, not editing, cropping, &c)?

Tags: screenshot

All articles I find that attempt to answer this say "Use Shutter! It lets you crop a screenshot while you take it!"  But cropping is not exact and it's just as bad as having to edit a normal screenshot afterward.

There are many services I use for work that require an image with an exact size, and even one pixel off renders an image useless.

Also, for clarity, I did try Shutter and it just didn't work; it couldn't capture just one window. It could only capture the whole monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a screenshot tool, then bind the appropriate command to take a screenshot of the current windows to a shortcut key.

For example, you could install `gnome-screenshot`, then bind the following command to a shortcut key:

```
gnome-screenshot -w
```

You can learn about the command line options for the tool with the command `man gnome-screenshot`.

`gnome-screenshot` is the tool used by default in versions of the Gnome Desktop before 40.